# Object Invisible in render - Blender 3.3.1

Tags: rendering, objects

I have been making a cupcake as you can see below:
[image: Cupcake Viewport]

But when I went to render it:
[image: Cupcake Render]

You can see that a part is missing in the middle.
So far I have done these to try and fix the problem:
F3 -> Clear render region and look if the camera was disabled in render in scene collection.

If you would like me to send you more info about the object, you can ask and I'll get it to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't get to find how to delete this post but it might be helpful for some people that could be experiencing the same issue. It rather is a straightforward fix, if the previous ones didn't work then you might want to look into your timeline. I found out that a key was removing the object from the render, so when I deleted it, it fixed the issue!